# Trouble with word wrapping

Tags: android, xml

I am having trouble getting a screen to appear as I would like it to be

The code below shows two lines of textview's 
First line is just a date textview, below this are 3 textviews with some data in. On the right hand side I have a button and I wish to have it span over the two lines.

trouble is the 3 textviews could have data that push into the button and instead of word wrapping the text is either above the button or pushes the button off the screen

Could anyone help me solve this

Thanks for your time

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/border_small">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- single date line -->
        <TextView 
            android:text=" - " 
                android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_8"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        </TextView>
    <!-- line under the date having 3 text fields -->
            <TextView 
                android:text=" TEST TEXT TEXT " 
            android:id="@+id/round" 
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_6"
                android:layout_below="@id/date">
            </TextView>
            <TextView 
                android:text="  -  " 
            android:id="@+id/spacer1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_6"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/_round" 
                android:layout_below="@id/date">
            </TextView>
            <TextView 
                android:text=" TEST TEXT TEXT " 
                android:id="@+id/classification" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spacer1" 
                android:layout_below="@id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_6">
     </TextView>

    <!-- button is on right hand side and spans both lines -->
            <Button 
                android:text="@string/button_view" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/button_details" 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_6" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the RelativeLayout

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that in your spacer1 TextView, you have this line: `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/_round"` You have an extra underscore in there. That's not your problem, though. Wrap your `date`, `round`, and `spacer1` TextViews in a Relative or Linear layout, and add the `android:layout_toLeftOf="button_details"` attribute to it. Should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting both android:layout_toRightOf and android:layout_toLeftOf on the text field(s) that need to use word wrap. So you might make the right-most TextView use this code:

```
<TextView 
            android:text=" TEST TEXT TEXT TEST TEXT TEXT TEST TEXT TEXT TEST TEXT TEXT TEST TEXT TEXT " 
            android:id="@+id/classification" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spacer1" 
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_details"
            android:layout_below="@id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </TextView>
```

Comment: I added this to the right hand one like you have shown but when I add "android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spacer1"" to the first textview will not load correct